# Can't understand this calculation in an integrational step for Vlasov-Poisson system

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am studying a paper by Rendall & Rein from 1993 (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9306021). The exact background is irrelevant, as I am just confused by a calculation they do seemingly without care. They set a matter distribution function in phase space $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$ to be
\begin{align}
f(t,x,v) = H (a^2(t) \big|v - \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t)} x\big|^2)
\end{align}
for a nonnegative function $H\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$. The mass density is its integral over $v$. All of this is clear. They state then, however, that
\begin{align}
\rho (t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(t,x,v) dv = a^{-3}(t) \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} H(v^2) dv.
\end{align}

I thought a lot about this and can't get into the fact that this should be obvious. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the translation $\tilde v = v - \frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)}x$. Since the integration is only with respect to $v$, we obtain $$\rho(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} H \bigg ( a^2(t) \bigg \vert v - \frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)}x \bigg \vert^2 \bigg) \, dv = \int_{\mathbb R^3} H \big ( a^2(t)  \vert \tilde v  \vert^2 \big) \, d \tilde v . $$ Next, assuming $a(t) \neq 0$, we make the rescaling $w = a(t) \tilde v$ to obtain $$\rho(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} H \big (   \vert w \vert^2 \big) (a(t))^{-3}\, d w =(a(t))^{-3}\int_{\mathbb R^3} H \big (   \vert v\vert^2 \big) \, d v  $$ as required.